# Google App Engine: Backends not responding

Tags: google-app-engine

I have been using google app engine for months now and have 2 hourly cron jobs in the backends.

For the past 24 hours we are seeing very strange behavior in the backends:

1. Both cron jobs are marked failed with no error. There is no trace in the logs that they started and failed.
2. When trying to upload a new version to the backend, the following error appeared: java.lang.RuntimeException: Version not ready.
3. I also tried to stop the backend from the admin console but when I try to start it again I get a Server Error: "A server error has occurred."

Help! Anyone?

Answer (score 0):

There's some Server side issues occuring with GAE at the moment. They have also indicated a server-outage at Feb-29. Not sure if these are related.